# Should I create a SQL Non-Clustered Index, ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a wildcard search within my web application, it's used a lot to help the user search for clients.
I currently only have indexes on the Id columns.

I appear to be getting deadlocks more often, this may be down to not having the correct indexes in place?

I have 3 tables that need to pull back data (and two that are searched)

```
public IEnumerable<Client> FindAllByWildCard(string accountId, string name)
{
    return RepositorySet
               .Include("Address")
               .Include("Invoice")
               .Where(p => (p.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) || 
                            p.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()) || 
                            p.Address.Line1.Contains(name) ||
                            p.Address.ZipCode.Contains(name) ||
                            p.Telephone.Contains(name))
                          && p.AccountId == accountId && !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

Should I create an index?

Comment: Wildcard queries in general are difficult to optimize but in this case make sure you have an index on `AccountId`. Deadlocks are often a symptom that index/query tuning is need to avoid large scans.

Comment: Also, what isolation level is the SELECT query running at?

Comment: Without knowing **which** queries are actually causing deadlocks, it's impossible to know whether adding an index on the columns you've shown will help. Deadlocks are most often caused by a badly-designed DB, not missing indexes.

Comment: Also consider setting your database to READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT.  That way SELECT queries using READ COMMITTED will not require any locks, and so can't participate in deadlocks.

Comment: Your best bet is to inspect the deadlock graph (and potentially post it on https://dba.stackexchange.com/) as it will tell you what statements and object participated in the deadlocks.